# Java программирование в Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, ооп, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Создал 2 файла: Users.java и Main.java. Но связать не могу их. в файле Users пишет, что нету метода main. Как мне программировать в текстовом редакторе и связывать между собой файлы?
Error Main method not found in class Users

Main.java

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Users alex = new Users(23, "Alexey");
        alex.PrintInfo();
    }
}
```

Users.java

```
public class Users{

    public int age;
    public String name;

    public Users(int _age, String _name){
        age = _age;
        name = _name;
    }

    public void PrintInfo(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ". Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут где-то подвох 

Comment: Покажите код и расскажите как Вы его пытаетесь скомпилировать. Скопируйте текст ошибки полностью и скопируйте его  в вопрос. Если классы большие, то пострайтесь упростить код. Желательно оставить только обращение из одного класса, для демонстрации, а все остальное убрать. Так получится [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Error Main method not found in class Users

Comment: Скорее всего Вы запускаете класс `Users` (`java Users`), а надо `Main` (`java Main`). Покажите команды компиляции и запуска.

Comment: Чисто ради интереса, чем вас Idea или Eclipse или уж VSCode не устроили?

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас все настроено правильно (прописан путь к папке `bin` `jdk`), то просто скомпилируйте проект из файла `Main.java` нажатием `ctrl + b`. Не забудьте также импортировать Ваш класс `Users` в файл `Main.java`. Чтоб не морочиться, можно просто объединить два класса в [пакет](http://proglang.su/java/packages)

В users.java:

```
package ru.myProject;
public class Users {
...
}
```

Ну и в main.java тот же самый пакет указываем

```
package ru.myProject;
```

Название пакета должно совпадать с названием папки в которой лежат файлы проекта.